# Request POST for Facebook in My Profile

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I will try to be as specific as possible. I am trying to make a request by POST method to publish a certain link in my profile. I've used the Facebook API, but it's not what I need. I need to do this:

[Image of Share a Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tLD6.png)

When I click click publish, I should post it to my profile, I need to do this without the Facebook API. I have noticed that clicking on the 'post' button makes a post request, but I do not know how to do it in Python.

I left in this link the buttons that are used to share.

[jornadahci.com/test/test.html](http://jornadahci.com/test/test.html)

I would appreciate your cooperation.

Thanks for you.

Edit: I did it with the Facebook API, it worked perfect. But now, I want to do it without the API and perform the automatic script. What causes me doubt is POST requests, if you note, when you click on 'publish' you will make about three requests. Also, I do not know if the script would need a cookie to know what account this.

Comment: No one is going to write your code for you. What do you want to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get?

Comment: @jdv I did it with the Facebook API, it worked perfect. But now, I want to do it without the API and perform the automatic script. What causes me doubt is POST requests, if you note, when you click on 'publish' you will make about three requests. Also, I do not know if the script would need a cookie to know what account this ...

Comment: Please don't put clarifications into comments. Put details related to the question in the body of the question by Editing it. But note that if you are asking for someone to give you some python code, it isn't going to happen.

Comment: @jdv Okay, I've put it there

Comment: You are going to have to be clearer. What is an "automatic script"? What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: @jdv Okay, I mean the script shared me by that button to my profile just by calling it ... the logic of the script I think I know how it is: make the post requests, use the library requests to connect to those requests but not I know how the script will recognize my Facebook account

Comment: Still very unclear what you actually want now ... The example page you have shown uses a 3rd-party service for sharing, AddThis. If you have questions about how to configure their script/service, then you should go check their documentation first.